# show that $x^3+2y^3+4z^3=9w^3$ has no nontrivial solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

show that $x^3+2y^3+4z^3=9w^3$ has no nontrivial solutions.

I'm really stuck on this.  If I use congruences, we will always have that the left is congruent to the right mod m if they are all multiples of m, so that is not helping me.

Comment: I assume you mean integral solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that $\gcd(x,y,z,w) = 1$. Then note that
$$a^3 \equiv \begin{cases}0\\1\\8 \end{cases} \pmod 9$$
Hence,
$$x^3 + 2y^3 + 4z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$$ only when $x,y,z \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. But this gives us $w \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ contradicting the fact that $\gcd(x,y,z,w) = 1$.

Comment: I'm almost there...how does this show there are no integer solutions?  Why does the gcd = 1 tell us there are no integer solutions?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst We obtain that $x,y,z,w ,\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, which means $3$ divides $x,y,z,w$.

Comment: Right, but why assume in the first place that the gcd is 1?  What does that matter?  It seems that there are solutions if x, y, z, have the form 9k, 9k+3 or 9k+6 right?.  My question is this.  Why assume the gcd is one, what does that matter, and how is that helpful?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst If $(x,y,z,w)$ satisfy $x^3+2y^3+4z^4 = 9w^3$ and $\gcd(x,y,z,w) = d > 1$, we can write $x = dx_1$, $y = dy_1$, $z = dz_1$ and $w = dw_1$ and cancel off the $d$'s to see that we need $x_1^3+2y_1^3+4z_1^4 = 9w_1^3$.

Comment: So by assuming that they're relatively prime, you have all integers in their reduced state.  Then since you arrive at a contradiction, we don't change the assumption and the equation is unsolvable.  I get it now i think.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Yes. We do not change the assumption. All we are doing is, if they have a common factor then pull out the common factor and then attack the problem.